# exhibit timeline date format

Tags: date, format, timeline, simile

I have an exhibit timeline, my data is in format "2013-12-15T07:39:19.000-04:00" and I'd like to control how the date is displayed. Right now, it displays only day and month by default but I'd like it to display year as well.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is *exhibit* using .js code?
If you want to format date to string the way you want,
Javascript can be tricky and you might have to parse on your own.
Something like this:

```
d = new Date("2013-12-15T07:39:19.000-04:00")
date_str =  d.getDate() +"-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getFullYear()
alert(date_str) //result depends on local computer timezone
```

Consider adding js library specific for date formatting, like *momment.js* (I have not tried it though)